# Lucene 8.4.1 - LatLonShape.createIndexableFields vs RecursivePrefixTreeStrategy.createIndexableFields

Tags: java, lucene

I'm working with Lucene Version 8.4.1 and got some questions about spatial indexing.
Its about performance and later on spatial searching. My test data are about 10000 Polygons. Thats the small data set.

First of all my setup:

```
            // JtsSpaticalContext is needed to index polygons
            this.ctx = JtsSpatialContext.GEO;
            SpatialPrefixTree tree = new GeohashPrefixTree(this.ctx, MAX_LEVEL);
            this.strategy = new RecursivePrefixTreeStrategy(tree, GEOMETRY_FIELDNAME);
            this.shapeReader = this.ctx.getFormats().getWktReader();
            // Creating the path for lucene index files
            Path path = Paths.get(INDEX_FOLDER);
            this.dir = SimpleFSDirectory.open(path);
            
            // preparing IndexWriter
            IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(new StandardAnalyzer());           
            config.setOpenMode(OpenMode.CREATE);
            config.setRAMBufferSizeMB(256.0);
            config.setUseCompoundFile(false);           
            config.setMaxBufferedDocs(IndexWriterConfig.DISABLE_AUTO_FLUSH);
            
            LogMergePolicy policy = new LogDocMergePolicy();
            policy.setMergeFactor(15);
            config.setMergePolicy(policy);
            
            this.indexWriter = new IndexWriter(dir, config);
```

As you can see I am using the JtsSpatialContext for indexing my spatial data. The config is still some magic for me, this consulation was given me the best results. **MAX_LEVEL** of the GeohashPrefixTree is set to 11. Also: *this.shapeReader = this.ctx.getFormats().getWktReader* is used to get rid of the *Deprecated* warning which is shown when I'm using *ctx.readFromWkt*. I watched at the *SpatialExample.java* from the official Lucene Github Repo [Github Repo SpatialExample](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/188f620208012ba1d726b743c5934abf01988d57/lucene/spatial-extras/src/test/org/apache/lucene/spatial/SpatialExample.java#L115)

Now as I said I want to index ~10000 Polygons which is in my use case the small data set. I got two approaches to index those data, differed by *CaseA* and *CaseB*

Here is my logic how I add those Polygons to my index:

```
        // Start Case A
        List<String> testDataCaseA = new ArrayList<>();     
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            testDataCaseA.add("POLYGON((9.0842201 48.80324419974113,9.084344 48.803237199741126,9.0843574 48.80333909974109,9.0842334 48.8033461997411,9.0842201 48.80324419974113))");
        }
        
        long startCaseA = System.nanoTime();

        testDataCaseA.parallelStream().forEach(current -> {
            try {
                this.indexWriter.addDocument(createDocumentCaseA(current));
            } catch (InvalidShapeException | IOException | java.text.ParseException e) {
                logger.error(e.toString());
            }
        });
        
        double elapsedTimeCaseA = (System.nanoTime() - startCaseA) / 1000000;
        logger.trace("Elapsed Time: " + elapsedTimeCaseA + "ms");
        // End Case A
        
        // Deleting the index
        this.indexWriter.deleteAll();
        
        // Start Case B
        List<String> testDataCaseB = new ArrayList<>(); 
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            testDataCaseB.add("{\"type\":\"Polygon\",\"coordinates\":[[[9.0842201,48.80324419974113],[9.084344,48.803237199741126],[9.0843574,48.80333909974109],[9.0842334,48.8033461997411],[9.0842201,48.80324419974113]]]}");
        }
        
        long startCaseB = System.nanoTime();
        
        testDataCaseB.parallelStream().forEach(current -> {
            try {
                this.indexWriter.addDocument(createDocumentCaseB(current));
            } catch (java.text.ParseException | IOException e) {
                logger.error(e.toString());
            }
        });
        
        double elapsedTimeCaseB = (System.nanoTime() - startCaseB) / 1000000;
        logger.trace("Elapsed Time: " + elapsedTimeCaseB + "ms");
        // End Case B
```

And here are the *createDocumentCaseA* and *createDocumentCaseB* methods

```
    private Document createDocumentCaseA(String geom) throws java.text.ParseException, InvalidShapeException, IOException {
        Document doc = new Document();
        
        for (Field f : strategy.createIndexableFields(this.shapeReader.read(geom))) {
            doc.add(f);
        }
        
        return doc;
    }
    
    private Document createDocumentCaseB(String geom) throws java.text.ParseException {
        Document doc = new Document();
        
        for (Polygon poly : Polygon.fromGeoJSON(geom)) {
            for (Field f : LatLonShape.createIndexableFields(GEOMETRY_FIELDNAME, poly)) {
                doc.add(f);
            }
        }
        
        return doc;
    }
```

The difference between these two variants is astonishing:

> Case A Elapsed Time: 41522.0ms
>
> Case B Elapsed Time: 168.0ms

Well, I thought: "Hm, okay, then I just choose case B and all is fine".
But my problem is on the "understandable level": What is the "right way" of doing this? And: If I'm using spatial search, in CaseA I got the method *strategy.makeQuery(SpatialArgs)*, in CaseB I need to use *LatLonShape.createXYQuery(someStuff)*

Which is the way to choose? Am I missing something in the docs from Lucene?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this blog](https://www.elastic.co/blog/bkd-backed-geo-shapes-in-elasticsearch-precision-efficiency-speed) and the links from that post, which explains the difference between the two approaches (basically it's triangles vs boxes) and the pretty astonishing improvements offered by LatLonShape over RecursivePrefixTreeStrategy when indexing polygons.

In case anyone is interested I also looked at the query performance of Lucene versus various others ([GIT repo](https://github.com/neilireson/geospatial-polygon-benchmark)) and its does good.

Testing on an index of Geofabrik OSM England landuse polygons, querying with the same 10,000 random points/polygons on each:

```
Benchmark                                  Mode  Cnt   Score    Error  Units
GeotoolsBenchmark.pointIntersectsQuery    thrpt    3  13.640 ± 83.265  ops/s
GeotoolsBenchmark.polygonIntersectsQuery  thrpt    3   0.101 ±  0.422  ops/s
LuceneBenchmark.pointIntersectsQuery      thrpt    3   0.108 ±  0.514  ops/s
LuceneBenchmark.polygonIntersectsQuery    thrpt    3   0.092 ±  0.117  ops/s
MongoDbBenchmark.pointQuery               thrpt    3   0.095 ±  0.049  ops/s
MongoDbBenchmark.polygonQuery             thrpt    3   0.028 ±  0.022  ops/s
PostgisBenchmark.pointQuery               thrpt    3   0.091 ±  0.142  ops/s
PostgisBenchmark.polygonQuery             thrpt    3   0.065 ±  0.068  ops/s
```